# How do I fix R package issue Google Cloud?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, install.packages

I am using the Google Cloud, Jupiter notebook with R for analysis.

When installing a specific R package called STM from structuraltopicmodel.com, calling the library gets an error. Installing other packages gives no issue.

Installing works:

```
install.packages(stm)

R[write to console]: The downloaded source packages are in
‘/tmp/RtmpCnjirU/downloaded_packages’
```

Calling the library:

```
library(stm)

R[write to console]: Error in library(stm) : there is no package called ‘stm’
```

I think I tried every other approach in code to make it happen. Can anyone help me? You would be my hero of the day :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: `install.packages()` needs quotes around the name:  `install.packages("stm")`.

Comment: thanks for the reply :) I did with install.packages("stm")

Comment: What was printed by the install command?  If those two commands happened in different sessions, you may have installed to one library, and looked for the package in a different one.

Comment: yeah I think indeed that is the case, only Google cloud doesnt say how to switch libraries. and I got this by performing both installing the package and calling the library in one cell:
 
R[write to console]: The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpCnjirU/downloaded_packages’

R[write to console]: Error in library("stm") : there is no package called ‘stm’
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous> -> withVisible -> library

Also I now got this:
R[write to console]:  installation of package ‘stm’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Non-zero exit status probably signals an error.  That would explain why `library("stm")` fails.

Comment: What specific Google Cloud Product are you using? Are you installing the R package on a [Compute Engine instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/), on the [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works)?

Comment: I am using a Compute engine instance and AI Platform. Within there I use Jupiter Notebooks.

Comment: Open for any solution :)